# How to scale a problem involving heat and the flow of a viscous fluid?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, heat-equation, fluid-dynamics

I recently got set this problem and I was wondering if anyone would be able to give me some help on the later parts.

An incompressible thermal conducting fluid is contained between two infinite horizontal plates separated by a distance $H$. Initially the plates and fluid are at rest at temperature $T_0$. At time $t = 0$ the upper plate is raised to temperature $T_1 > T_0$ and moved horizontally at speed $U$.

(a) Assuming the fluid flow is lamina, show that the velocity and temperature field equations reduce to $v=p=0$ , $ \rho u_t(y,t)=\mu u_{yy}(y,t)$ and $\rho cT_t(y,t)=kT_{yy}(y,t) + \mu (u_y(y,t))^2$

(b) Scale the equations. What dimensionless groups govern the temperature and
velocity fields?

(c) Qualitatively discuss the processes set into play and indicate the time scales involved.

(d) Roughly how long does it take before steady conditions are reached.

(e) Determine the steady state temperature and velocity fields.

I have managed to do part (a). In part (b) I decided to let $y=Ly'$, $u=Uu'$, $t=t_{0}t'$ and $T=T_{0}+(T_{1}-T_{0})T'$ and ended up with $u'_{t'}=\frac{\mu t_{0}}{L^2 \rho}u'_{y'y'}$ and $T'_{t'}=\frac{kt_{0}}{\rho c L^2}T'_{y'y'} + \frac{\mu U^2 t_{0}}{L^2 \rho c (T_{1}-T_{0})}(u'_{y'})^2$, Therefore we take $t_{0}=\frac{L^2 \rho}{\mu}$ right? However I'm unsure about how to solve part(c) or (d), so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After setting $t_0=L^2\rho/\mu$, you dimensionless parameter is $U^2/(c(T_1-T_0))$ which I think is like the Eckert number. To solve the steady state problem, remove time dependence from the problem, i.e. make $u=u(y)$ so you get $u_{yy}(y)=0$ and $kT_{yy}(y)+\mu u_y^2(y)=0$ which give you the standard parabolic velocity profile, which you can use to find the (cubic) temperature profile.

Comment: I don't understand. When we let $t_{0}=\frac{L^2 \rho}{\mu}$, we get $u'_{t'}=u'_{y'y'}$ and $T'_{t'}=\frac{k}{c\mu}T'_{y'y'} +\frac{U^2}{c(T_{1}-T_{0})}(u'_{y'})^2$. So eliminating time, we get $u'_{y'y'}(y)=0$ as you said, but surely $kT'_{y'y'}(y)+\frac{U^2 \mu}{T_{1}-T_{0}}(u'_{y'}(y))^2=0$?

Comment: Also how can we solve $u'_{y'y'}(y)=0$? What would the initial conditions be?

Comment: Yes you are right, the equation should be $T_y(y)+E(u_y)^2=0$ where $E$ is a non-dimensional parameter (I didn't check the dimensions though). To solve $u_{yy}=0$, just integrate twice with respect to $y$, and the boundary conditions are $u=0$ at the top and bottom plates.

Comment: Why are the boundary conditions $u'=0$ at $y=0$ and $y=H$?

Comment: Sorry, that was incorrect. It should be $u=0$ at $y=0$ because the bottom plate is stationary. The other boundary condition is $u=1$ at $y=H/L$ (I think you should use $H$ as your length scale then you would impose this condition at $y=1$, because the top plate is moving at (non-dimensional) speed 1.

Comment: Yes I thought that as well, thanks for all your help!

Comment: This then gives the solution $u'(y')=y'$ right? Substituting this into the temperature equation we have $kT'_{y'y'}(y')+\frac{U^2\mu}{T_{1}-T_{0}}=0$ with boundary conditions $T'(0)=0$ and $T'(1)=1$?

Comment: So $T'(y')=(1+\frac{U^2\mu}{2k(T_{1}-T_{0})})y' - \frac{U^2\mu}{2k(T_{1}-T_{0})}y'^2$

Comment: Yes, $u(y)=y$. Then $T_{yy}=-E$ so $T=-Ey^2/2+(1+E/2)y$ I think ($E=\frac{\mu U^2}{k(T_1-T_0)}$)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for all your help :)